# How to add HTTP/2 in G-WAN

Tags: http, g-wan

I would like to know if it's possible to make G-WAN 100% compatible with HTTP/2 by using for example the solution nghttp2 (https://nghttp2.org)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer - for any reason Stackoverflow did not notify us this question and I have found it only because a more recent one was notified.

I have not looked at this library so I can't tell for sure if it can be used without modifications, but it could certainly be used as the basis of an *event-based* G-WAN `protocol handler`.

But, from a ***security*** point of view, there are severe issues with HTTP-2, and this is why we have not implemented it in G-WAN: ***HTTPS-2 lets different servers use the same TCP connection - even if    they weren't listed in the original TLS certificate***.

That may be handy for legit applications, but that's a problem for security: DOH (DNS over HTTP-2) prevents users from blocking (or even detecting) unwanted hosts at the traditionally used DNS requests level (the "hosts" file in various operating systems).

In facts, this new HTTP standard is defeating the purpose of SSL certificates, and defeating domain-name monitoring and blacklisting.

Is it purely a theoretical threat?

Google *ads* have been used in the past to inject malware designed to attack *both* the client and server sides.

Comment: Can you please elaborate further on this: "HTTPS-2 lets different servers use the same TCP connection"

Comment: https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc7540.html#reuse and DoH (DNS over HTTP) are good examples.

Comment: Google has recently announced HTTP-3 which is incompatible with HTTP-2 as it now relies on UDP instead of TCP (a very long-awaited and overdue move: DDoS attacks will no longer exploit TCP handshakes - providing that the HTTP-3 authentication is done right...).